# Could not create type 'myProject.Service1' with vb on localhost

Tags: vb.net, iis

I am attempting to host a web service in my IIS Manager and I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
```

I read this happens when I change the name of the class and don't change it in the markup, however I have both changed

```
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
```

Source Error States

```
Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.vb" Class="myApp.Service1" %>
```

My Markup

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.vb" Class="myApp.Service1" %>
```

All I have read seems to reference the name not matching but I have left mine all default to prevent this issue and I still get the same issue.

Comment: did you build the application after doing all the changes? is your bin folder is available under your site folder? which version of application pool you are using did you change the project type from website to web application or vice versa?

Comment: i had forgotten to build my application. Thanks Jalpa

Comment: I posted the solution, I request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the application after doing changes and then again publish the application.